# How to use MAX in subquery in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am trying to write my first query in LINQ
This is my SQL query

```
SELECT P.id,PS.Id,P.CPersonName
,PS.StartDate FROM Provider P
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProviderSubscription PS ON
P.id=PS.providerID
AND PS.Id=(SELECT max(id)from ProviderSubscription where
providerSubscription.ProviderId=Provider.id)
```

And so far i wrote this LINQ.

```
    var query = (from p in db.Providers
                     join ps in db.ProviderSubscriptions on  p.Id 
                     equals ps.ProviderId
                    select new ViewModel
                     {
                         providerid = p.Id,
                         providername = p.ProviderName,
                         subscriptiondate = ps.ExpiryDate,
                       }).ToList();
```

I am unable to add this part in my LINQ.

```
 AND PS.Id=(SELECT max(id)from ProviderSubscription where
 providerSubscription.ProviderId=Provider.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a subquery, when you're doing a join with same tables and with same conditions then there is NO need to again write an inner query with same tables. Below query should return same result:

```
   var query = (from p in db.Providers
          join ps in db.ProviderSubscriptions on  p.Id equals ps.ProviderId
          where ps.Contains(ps.Max(u=>u.id))
          select new ViewModel
             {
                 providerid = p.Id,
                 providername = p.ProviderName,
                 subscriptiondate = ps.ExpiryDate,
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: getting error 'ProviderSubscription' does not contain a definition for 'contains' . any idea for that. thanks

Comment: well, try this: exact LINQ version of your sql query 


 var query = (from p in db.Providers
              join ps in db.ProviderSubscriptions on  p.Id equals ps.ProviderId
              let s = from pro in dc.ProviderSubscription 
                      where pro.id == p.id
                      select pro.id
              where s.contains(ps.Max(u=>u.id))
              select new ViewModel
                 {
                     providerid = p.Id,
                     providername = p.ProviderName,
                     subscriptiondate = ps.ExpiryDate,
                   }).ToList();

Comment: and btw I hope you tried with capital 'Contains', have you?

Comment: @ Shilpa I havent tried first with capital C.Now the problem is  with Max.